# Load objects from file to arrayList

Tags: java

I wonder how I should do to read objects from a list if I don't know how many object there are? To save is easier because than I use the number of objects that I have in the ArrayList where I store all objects. Code like this:

```
// Save all customer object from customerList
for(int j=0; j < customerList.size(); j++) {
    outObjectStream.writeObject(customerList.get(j));
}
```

My thought was to use something similar to load all objects in the file and add them one after one to the ArrayList after it has been cleared. But as I wrote, it's not possible when I don't know the number of object inside the file. Any ideas how I can solve this in simple way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your design is flawed: You should be serializing the *List* to file, not each Customer object. Then you would just deserialize the whole List.

After deserializing you will have a new instance of the list. If you absolutely *must* load the customers into *your* list, use `customerList.addAll(list);`

All of the common [`Collections`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) are themselves [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html): Use and trust the JDK API!

Comment: OK, Then I perhaps I should change my code and save the customer the arraylist then, but would I load the arraylist just like this: inObjectStream.readObject(customerList) and the be ready to use the arraylist again, and no need to do soemthing else?

Comment: @3D-kreativ - I suggest you try it and see rather than asking a "did you really mean that?" style follow-up question.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `outObjectStream.writeObject(customerList);` and let the ObjectInputStream do the job while reading it back.

Comment: Hmm, but if I want to load the customerList, how does it "connect" to the customerList that I have in the code, or do I not need to do anything else after that I have loaded the customerList?! Is it enough to just use somethong like: inObjectStream.readObject(customerList); and then just be happy and continue working with the arrayList!? :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `ArrayList.add()`. The number of elements is not required to be known beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

To *read* objects from a file into a list you need to read it back in the opposite way you wrote it:

```
readObject(...)
```

rather than:

```
writeObject(...)
```

However, you really wouldn't normally want to save each object separately. One should either save the whole list at one as one object or ideally save it to a more readable format such as CSV, XML or JSON etc.

Writing and Reading objects gets tricky when you start changing your objects (adding new fields etc.).